# expressJs router.post() not working for multiple middleware giving [object Undefined] error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

i am creating a REST API for my users, and i used express-validator for the validation before creating the user in the database.. but when i chain my middleware together in the router.py file it gives the error `Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`
i imported my middleware and controller from thier respective files.

here is the code in my router.py

```
const express = require('express');
const authMiddleware = require('../middlewares/authMiddleware');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

const router = express.Router();

router.post(
  '/signup',
  authMiddleware.verifySignUpInit(),
  authMiddleware.verifySignUp,
  authController.signup
);

module.exports = router;
```

in my middleware file i added this..

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { authentication } = require('../config');
const { User } = require('../models');
const { body } = require('express-validator');

const verifySignUpInit = () => {
  return [
    body('email', 'email is required').exists().normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
    body('phone', 'phone is required').exists().isInt(),
    body('first_name', 'first_name is required').exists().isString(),
    body('last_name', 'last_name is required').exists().isString(),
    body('password', 'password is required').exists(),
  ];
};

const verifySignUp = (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, phone, password } = req.body;

  User.findOne({
    email,
  }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        status: 'error',
        message: err,
      });
    }
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'failed',
        message: 'Email Provided Already Exists',
      });
    }
  });
  User.findOne({
    phone,
  }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        status: 'error',
        message: err,
      });
    }
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'failed',
        message: 'Phone Provided Already Exists',
      });
    }
  });
  const password_is_valid = authentication.passwordSchema.validate(password);
  if (!password_is_valid) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: 'failed',
      message: 'password requirements not met',
    });
  }
  next();
};

module.exports = {
  verifySignUpInit,
  verifySignUp,
};
```

and finally in my controller i have this..

```
const config = require('../config');
const db = require('../models');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const { User, Role } = db;
const { token_expiry_time, refresh_token_expiry_time } = config.authentication;

const signUp = (req, res) => {
  const { email, phone, first_name, last_name, password } = req.body;
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: 'failed',
      message: errors.array(),
    });
  }
  bcrypt.hash(password, 8, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        status: 'error',
        message: err,
      });
    }
    const user = new User({
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      password: hash,
    });

    Role.findOne({ name: 'is_user' }, (err, role) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
          status: 'error',
          message: err,
        });
        return;
      }
      user.roles = [role._id];
      user.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({
            status: 'error',
            message: err,
          });
        }

        return res.status(201).json({
          status: 'success',
          data: {
            user,
          },
        });
      });
    });
  });
};


module.exports = {
  signUp,
};
```

i cant tell what i am doing wrong :(

Comment: Not the source of the problem you're asking about, but your `verifySignUp()` function does not work properly as it calls `User.findOne(...).exec()` and without waiting for that to complete, calls that again and without waiting for that to complete calls `next()` - so it will always just end up calling `next()` and the other parts of the logic will just generate errors.

Comment: I'd suggest you add this before your `router.post()` to debug: `console.log(typeof authMiddleware.verifySignUpInit(), typeof authMiddleware.verifySignUp, typeof  authController.signup);` and see which one is causing the problem.  FYI, this is somewhat elemental debugging to take these next steps to narrow down your problem.  You should be doing things like this before you come here.

Comment: thanks for the help... but i console.logged what they were before i came here.. they where all valid.. the person below helped me out .. it was just a simple typo in my authController imports :) i'll take note of the User.findOne tho...

Comment: I am the person below.  If you did a `console(authController.signup)`, you would have seen `undefined`.  So, you must not have done a `console.log()` of the actual capitalization you were using.

Comment: i did console.log() for the top ones where it told me the error occured so that confused me so i came here.. but i'll attempt to do that from now on.. thanks

Comment: concernig the `User.findOne(..)` does this look better?

`const userEmailTest = await User.findOne({ email });
const userPhoneTest = await User.findOne({ phone });`

Comment: That is the general idea.  You also don't want to call `next()` if you've already sent a response (as in all your error conditions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
authController.signup
```

should be:

```
authController.signUp
```

You have to use the same capitalization for the property name you exported.

Comment: wow... a simple solution, that work perfectly fine <3 thank you...